# Prove that the next function $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need help in this exercise. What I need to prove that the function $f$ given  is not continuous in the point $(0,0)$

$$ f(x,y) = \begin {cases} \frac {x^3\times y} {x^6+y^2} & (x,y) \not = 0\\ 0 & (x,y) = 0 \end {cases} $$

So what I've done so far is to calculate the limit of the function in the first place with two variables:

> $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to\ (0,0)} \frac {x^3\times y} {x^6+y^2} $$
>   I substitute $y=mx$ which is the slope
>   $$ \lim_{(x)\to\ (0)} \frac {x^3\times mx} {x^6+(mx)^2} $$
>   $$=\lim_{(x)\to\ (0)} \frac {x^4\times m} {x^6+m^2x^2} $$
>   $$=\lim_{(x)\to\ (0)} \frac {x^4\times m} {x^2(x^6+m^2)} $$
>   $$=\lim_{(x)\to\ (0)} \frac {x^2\times m} {x^6+m^2} $$
>   $$=\lim_{(x)\to\ (0)} \frac {x^2\times m} {x^6+m^2} $$
>   $$=\frac {0^2\times m} {0^6+m^2} = 0$$

So my result says that it is continuous.
What have I done wrong? What do I need to do to prove that it is not if I already calculated that it is?
Thank you so much. If something isn't very clear, please let me know.

Comment: $x^2/x^6 = 1/x^4$ and $0/0 \neq 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We consider the path $y=x^3$ to $(0,0)$. Along this path, the function becomes
$$\frac{x^3\cdot x^3}{x^6+x^6}=\frac{x^6}{2x^6}=\frac12$$
and so the limit along this path is $\frac12$. Since this is different from the limit of 0 you obtained with the different path $y=mx$, the limit at the origin does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that by $x=u$ and $y=v^3$

$$\frac {x^3 y} {x^6+y^2}=\frac {u^3 v^3} {u^6+v^6}$$

which is a simpler case to handle.